# Calculating execution time of function in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to calculate the execution time of sorting function(bubblesort) by putting it into the other function which can compute the elapsed time.. 
but it keeps showing me time : 0 as i run it...

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A_SIZE 100000

void executeTime(int func);
int bubble(int A[], int l, int r);


int main()
{
    int A[A_SIZE], i;
    int l = 0, r = A_SIZE - 1;

    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < A_SIZE; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    executeTime(bubble(A, l, r));
}

void executeTime(int func) {
    int start_s = clock();
    func;
    int stop_s = clock();
    cout << "time: " << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000 << endl;
}

int bubble(int A[], int l, int r)
{
    int i, j, min;

    for (i = l; l < r - 1; l++)
    {
        min = A[i];
        for (j = l + 1; j < r; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < min)
            {
                min = A[j];
                A[j] = A[i];
                A[i] = min;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But if i write all the code in the main block, instead of creating discrete functions which compute the time and sorting array, it works just fine as i intended.
What is the problem here? Why i'm getting 'time : 0' on the screen??

Comment: Spend a few weeks reading a good C++ programming book, then look into some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). You have a huge misunderstanding, and **we can't teach you C++ here.**

Comment: `func;` is not a function call (and `int func` does not pass a function as parameter, it's just a single value - in this case the result of `bubble`)

Comment: `executeTime(bubble(A, l, r));` is equivalent to `int temp = bubble(A, l, r); executeTime(temp);` hence not what you think

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler and it will point at `func;` and say "statement has no effect" or something similar.

Comment: What you're passing as parameter of function `executeTime()` is not a function but an single integer value (this is what specifies the prototype `void executTime(int func))`. Then when you call `executTime(bubble(A, l, r));` you are in fact passing the result of `bubble(A, l, r)` (which is an integer) to `executTime()`. `bubble(A, l, r)` is called before your program enters `executeTime()` and therefore before the first call of `clock()`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Are you having a bad day dude or are you normally like this?

Comment: @d9ngle: It should not matter to you (indeed my thumb is broken and hurts). But SO users cannot expect an answer as long as a book, so I am normally like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a function to `executeTime` and not the result of a function. Your mistake is that you execute the bubble sort and pass the returned value to `executeTime`. You have to call the function within `executeTime`. There are different ways to achieve this. You can use function pointers or  `std::function<int(int*, int, int)>` (C++11).

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A_SIZE 100000

typedef int FUNCTION_POINTER(int*, int, int);

void executeTime(FUNCTION_POINTER func, int* A, int i, int j);
int bubble(int A[], int l, int r);

int main()
{
    int A[A_SIZE], i;
    int l = 0, r = A_SIZE - 1;

    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < A_SIZE; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    executeTime(&bubble, A, l, r);
}

void executeTime(FUNCTION_POINTER func, int* A, int i, int j) {
    int start_s = clock();
    func(A, i, j);
    int stop_s = clock();
    cout << "time: " << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000 << endl;
}

int bubble(int A[], int l, int r)
{
    int i, j, min;

    for (i = l; l < r - 1; l++)
    {
        min = A[i];
        for (j = l + 1; j < r; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < min)
            {
                min = A[j];
                A[j] = A[i];
                A[i] = min;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##pVLfb9owEH73X3FqpSmBsNLXJqsUISahVVAV@jKEouAY5ixxosSeNk387fTODiWUhz3MDz7r7rvvfnzmdT3ac3483krFC5MJiLiWpXhkPUers0Ju@y7n@fyj75NVqxuRlo/MtFLtQaWlaOuUC0B0yNhtJnZSCYiT5ez7FO7HdBjTf2qBEZBKw9fX@WQ1W8yT58Vsvpq@eOgcBBSyl48svyqZgfgtuNFihY16H3NgZxS38AHE1oJ0Jsd8sluz3RaCuCFeb1yscKahEvQoU6k8n/1lgMchXd@ED9@9BXyBcQANmm6sEdwjBcXbJlWZ5xnVyr0SmR2AVuuNfd8x7KoGbBuSaEI0UUeD7@HQtyDXAp14LTcItLQdw8GV6u/jkxsvoOFxKpro8J9rg/MaWp02OmmxDV5U/OepD0r2KC2wWz6jq/oazCujIYrghrbxADf09jro6FTBhzvIKkNCTZ4Wk2/L5Hn6kiynEx8G9u9QllBZYcf7p6w9JanHAEqpOp2cCthkEaKeEYpJGkJxLQDmkNAoQ/jus9k5ZcOQ0nJiQHPKvmSwPezAi9f5BoFI6F/ELpH9mnmv5vlD5Jurhj78Fjtn339gly93N0KbRuEnZIfj8Q0)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot how to use function pointers but i do know now!

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes, some more and some less severe. Plus, the code completely changed while I was writing this.

The main reason, first and foremost, why it didn't work is that you execute `bubble()` which unconditionally returns a zero integer (for no good reason). Then you pass that integer to the timing function and "execute" the integer.
In other words, what you tell the compiler to do is "do nothing" inside the timing loop (empty statement). This, obviously, doesn't measure an awful lot.

You probably *meant to* pass a function pointer rather than the function's return value. *The recent edit (which totally changes the question, btw) suggests that this was exactly your intent*.
If you didn't return an integer on a function that could as well be `void` (it never returns anything useful) then there's a good chance the compiler would have told you that you're trying to use an integer as function pointer.

The next problem is that you didn't honor the four rules of benchmark:

1. All benchmarks suck. Those that don't suck are biased.
2. Benchmarks with insufficient timing suck more.
3. Benchmarks with too small workload suck particularly.
4. Benchmarks with one run suck totally.

You execute a function, which although well-known to be a poor performer, will likely run very fast since the array's size is only 100,000. Also, you only execute it once, so there's additional biasing effects such as instruction cache being cold and the processor likely being in a low power state. Modern processors are in low power state almost all the time -- unless you run some "warm up" code first.

The resolution of `clock` is microseconds (regardless of actual timer resolution), so even assuming you did measure "properly", the result would likely be somewhere in the single digit range. That's not useful because it's way too coarse to tell something.
If you compare the speed of two cars, and your measurement returns either 5 or 6 (depending on rounding), you cannot really tell much about them, can you.